# When did the NFL move the stanchion out of the end zone?

Tags: trivia, american-football, nfl, history

I was just watching a clip of Bart Starr's game-winning quarterback sneak in the [Ice Bowl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1967_NFL_Championship_Game).  One thing I noticed is that the goal post stanchion is inside the end zone, not behind the end zone as it is nowadays.  That must have been interesting back then, with receivers and defensive backs possibly colliding with the stanchion if they weren't paying attention, or receivers using the stanchion as a screen.

Anyway, when did the NFL move the stanchion outside of the end zone?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the NFL began in 1920, the goal posts were on the goal line. In addition, the goal posts were shaped like an H with two stanchions also located directly on the goal line. The NCAA moved the goal posts to the back of the end zone in 1927 and the NFL did the same, as they were using the NCAA rule book at the time. In 1933, the NFL started writing their own rule book and returned the goal posts to the goal line in order to encourage more field goals.

In 1967, the “slingshot” shaped goal posts were invented, with only one stanchion located further behind the goal post uprights.

In 1974, the NFL decided to move the goal posts to the back of the end zone once again, with the lone stanchion behind that, in an attempt to encourage more touchdowns and fewer field goals.

Sources:

- Wikipedia: [Field Goal: History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_goal#History)
- Sports Illustrated: [“The History of NFL Goal Posts: Excitement And Danger”](https://www.si.com/mmqb/2017/06/21/history-nfl-goal-posts)